# Scala подскажите пожалуйста

Tags: scala

Реализовать метод ньютона для решения уравнения ( x^3+18*x-83 = 0)

```
Import scala.math.abs

object laba1
{
def square(x: Double) = x * x

def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
(guess + x / guess) / 2

def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
abs(square(guess) - x) < 0.001

def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
if (isGoodEnough(guess, x))
guess
else
sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

def sqrt(x: Double) = sqrtIter(1.0, x)

def main(args: Array[String])
{
var x = 0
println("Корень из " + x + " is " + sqrt(x))
}
}
```

Не понимаю как сделать чтобы решал уравнение

Comment: Я не знаю что такое "метод Ньютона". Сформулируй вопрос который тебя интересует касательно языка Scala.

Comment: `x = x - f(x) / f'(x)` и т.д., пока значение `f(x)` не станет достаточно близким к нулю. `f` - сама функция, `f'` - ее первая производная, в качестве начального `x` можно взять, например, ноль.

Comment: У меня есть уравнение, не пойму как его вставить, есть другая реализация кода, именно под уравнение подстроить не получается

Comment: import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.math.abs
object NewtonMethod {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val accuracy = 1e-6
@tailrec
def method(x0: Double, f: Double => Double, dfdx: Double => Double, e: Double): Double = {
val x1 = x0 - f(x0) / dfdx(x0)
if (abs(x1 - x0) < e) x1
else method(x1, f, dfdx, e)
}
def g(C: Double) = (x: Double) => x * x - C
def dgdx(x: Double) = 2 * x
def sqrt(x: Double) = x match {
case 0 => 0
case x if (x < 0) => Double.NaN
case x if (x > 0) => method(x / 2, g(x), dgdx, accuracy)
println(method(0,x*x*x+18*x-83,2 * x*x+18,0.00001))
}

}
}

Answer (score 0):

В коде из вопроса решается задача нахождения квадратного корня из числа. В Вашем [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100068/scala-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0#comment1896437_1100068) приведён код, работающий с произвольными функциями. Для его использования нужно передать функцию и её производную в качестве параметров `f` и `dfdx` метода

```
def method(x0: Double, f: Double => Double, dfdx: Double => Double, e: Double): Double
```

Можно написать методы

```
def fun(x: Double) : Double = x*x*x+18*x-83
def dfun(x: Double) : Double = 3*x*x+18
```

и вызвать так:

```
method(0, fun, dfun, 0.000001)
```

Но более идиоматичный подход -- использование лямба-выражений:

```
method(0, x => x*x*x+18*x-83, x => 3*x*x+18, 0.00001)
```